# Strange behavior of Manipulate with arbitrary number of control variables

Tags: functions, manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

I am creating a `Manipulate` that evaluates a function that takes an arbitrary number of binary control variables. For example, the `Manipulate` takes in three control variables `{a,b,c}` and returns the function `f[ls_]:=DeleteDuplicates[ls]`. Some minimal working examples show different ways to accomplish this:

```
f[ls_] := DeleteDuplicates[ls];

m1[controls_] := Manipulate[f[controls], 
    Grid[{Map[Control[{{#, 1}, {0, 1}}] &, controls]}]];

m2[controls_] := Manipulate[f[controls], 
    Grid[{Map[Function[x, Evaluate[Control[{{x, 1}, {0, 1}}]]],
    controls]}]];

m3[controls_] := Manipulate @@ {f[controls], 
    Grid[{Map[Control[{{#, 1}, {0, 1}}] &, controls]}]};

m1[{a,b,c}] // Print;
m2[{a,b,c}] // Print;
m3[{a,b,c}] // Print;
```

As might be expected, function `m1` returns the error that the argument specifying the control variables does not have the right form. To rectify this, function `m2` uses `Function[x,...]` instead of a pure function. But what happens here is the control variable `x` gets defined repeatedly. Function `m3` rectifies this by using `@@`, but when `f` gets evaluated it isn't able to figure out that `a=b=c`, so returns the strange result that `DeleteDuplicates[{a,b,c}]={1,1,1}`.

Output is shown below. The desired output in this case is {1}.

[image: Output]

What's going on here? Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Manipulate` has attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), so it maintains its arguments in unevaluated form. While still unevaluated, your control definitions are not in any of the expected formats, and so do not appear correct; you need to force evaluation of your control definitions within `Manipulate` using [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html). In fact, the fact that the contents of the list were evaluated before `Manipulate` was applied to it was the reason that `m3` worked, at least as far as generating a `Manipulate` object.

Here is a new definition that should achieve what you want:

```
Clear[f, m4]
f[ls_] := DeleteDuplicates[ls]
m4[controls_] := 
   Manipulate[f[controls], Evaluate@Row[Map[Control[{{#, 1}, {0, 1}}] &, controls]]]

m4[{a, b, c}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

.. and after toggling the value of e.g. `c`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]